# angular2 error in lodash js

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, lodash

I have tried to use lodash for datatable. Here is what I have tried:

- npm install lodash - gave cannot find package error
- searched issue and then tried npm install --save @types/lodash

this produced following output:

```
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY @angular/common@~2.1.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.4.6 invalid
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY @angular/core@~2.1.0
`-- @types/lodash@4.14.52
```

which I dont understand, since my package.json has following:

```
"@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
```

- after this, IDE can find package, but when I run npm start/ng serve I get multiple errors

  ERROR in [default] **path**\node_modules\@types\lodash\index.d.ts:192
  81:20 
  Cannot find namespace '_'.

  ERROR in [default] **path**\node_modules\@types\lodash\index.d.ts:190
  21:57 
  Cannot find name 'Many'.

  ERROR in [default] **path**\node_modules\@types\lodash\index.d.ts:194
  41:0 
  Declaration or statement expected.

and first two errors repeat multiple times each, but with different number (i guess line)

What should i do, to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what worked for me, was to get package.json file from another (working project) and run npm install. I still have no idea why mine didn't work, but that is what solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you are installing a old module(as written in your package.json) but it is not available on git due to update in their version.
for solving this issue

```
    1.Need to install the project’s local dependencies (that’s where it’s looking for lodash). To do that,
    2.cd into the project directory and run npm install.
    3.You can also try npm i --save lodash
```

If the package.json file exists, and if it contains the lodash dependency you could try to remove the node_modules folder and run following command:

```
$ npm cache clean    
$ npm install
```

The first command will clean the npm cache. (just to be sure) The second command will install all (missing) dependencies of the project.